# Accepting, canceling acceptance and accepting again gives 4 points

Tags: bug

Basically what the title says. I found today that if I cancel some accepted answer and afterwards accept it again, I still get an additional +2 on reputation (on stackoverflow).

Comment: +1 for honesty, but have you tried recalculating the reputation?

Comment: It happened some hours ago (I was about to post it at that time, but I kept being busy with work :$) but at the time I believe my calculations were correct.

Comment: no - go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and see what value it reports. Click on the recalculate button to get your "proper" rep. Try the experiment again. Then revisit the report and see what it reports.

Comment: Hmm I think it reports the same now. Why, what does recalculate do?

Comment: Your headline reputation doesn't change when question and answers are deleted (either directly by you or by migrations etc.) so diverges from your "true" reputation. Recalculate reruns all the calculations, ignoring these deleted posts (obviously) and resets your reputation to it's true value.

Comment: Ok but I have to do the recalculation manually? Or is it scheduled to happen over some period?

Comment: @George Kastrinis, you can do it manually. But it sometimes happens for all of us. Mostly when new procedures are implemented.

Comment: Thx for the infos :)

Comment: @chris where did the OP mention deletion? I see nothing about deletes in his post.

Comment: @Jeff - I was trying to explain why the reputation he sees on the site might not be accurate.

Comment: @GeorgeKastrinis is this still happening? I would guess that [the March changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) fixed it.